# Why are manually created indexes not compressed by default on ADW?

Tags: oracle, database-indexes, oracle-autonomous-db

On my ADW instance, indexes created by auto indexing are compressed by default but manually created indexes are not.

Why are manually created indexes not compressed by default?

```
Test case:
==========

SQL> create table a (a number);
Table created.

SQL> create index a_ind on a (a);
Index created.

SQL> select INDEX_NAME,COMPRESSION from dba_indexes where index_name='A_IND';
INDEX_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPRESSION
-------------
A_IND
DISABLED

SQL> drop index a_ind ;
Index dropped.

SQL> create index a_ind on a (a) compress;
Index created.

SQL> select INDEX_NAME,COMPRESSION from dba_indexes where index_name='A_IND';
INDEX_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPRESSION
-------------
A_IND
ENABLED
```

Answer (score 2):

Automatic indexing has a preference for index compression as documented here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/autonomous-auto-index.html#GUID-D51A4F85-3AE5-4B7D-9B27-32CEDE8DBD79

> Note: When automatic indexing is enabled, index compression for auto
> indexes is enabled by default.

As of today you need to specify compression for your indexes manually.